# Search Urdu text by Passing parameter in sql

Tags: sql, full-text-search, ssms-2017

```
    Declare @Topic nvarchar(2000) ='.کثیر الانتخاب جواب میں سے صحیح جواب منتخب کیجئے'

    SELECT  TextbookTopicId,Title FROM TextbookTopic tt WHERE tt.Title =@Topic
```

I declared a variable and use in where clause but its not working.
but if i use 'N' and remove variable from where clause and use text directly in where clause then it works fine

```
SELECT  TextbookTopicId,Title FROM TextbookTopic tt WHERE tt.Title =N'.کثیر الانتخاب جواب میں سے صحیح جواب منتخب کیجئے'
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and full text search is vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You need the `N` before the constant:

```
Declare @Topic nvarchar(2000) = N'.کثیر الانتخاب جواب میں سے صحیح جواب منتخب کیجئے';
```

Otherwise, the value is a `varchar()` constant that gets converted to `nvarchar()`.

Comment: i want to pass a dynamic parameter , how can i use 'N' with dynamic parameter

Comment: @Tayyeb . . . Just use an `nvarchar()` -- and then be sure that you set it properly.  The issue in your code is how you are *setting* the value, not how you are passing it.